# If $\frac{log 2}{log 3}$ is irrational how does it follow that both $1-\frac{1}{2^s}$ and $1-\frac{1}{3^s} $ can't be zero for the same s

Tags: laplace-transform, irrational-numbers

Wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function says:

[N]ow we can define correctly, where the denominators are not zero,

$\zeta(s) = \frac{\eta(s)}{1-\frac{2}{2^s}}$

or

$\zeta(s) = \frac{\lambda(s)}{1-\frac{3}{3^s}}$

Since $ \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} $ is irrational, the denominators in the two definitions are not zero at the same time except when s=1 ...

How does it follow? Any pointers to more detail appreciated.

Follow up question: I can see that both the denominators cannot be zero for the same value  $s \in \Bbb C (s \ne 1)$, but can any value of $s$ with these constraints make any one of the above denominators zero at all?

Considering 
$$1-3^{(1-s)} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 3^{(1-s)} = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-s) \log 3 = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-s) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 = s$$ which is excluded from the domain.

In other words, does $ 3^{1-s} = 1 $ have any other roots other than $s = 1$ when $s \in \Bbb C$

Comment: What about $s=1$?

Comment: Added "except s = 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the denominators are zero, then it follows that: $$1-2^{1-s}=1-3^{1-s} $$ $$\implies \left(\frac 23 \right) ^{1-s} =1$$

After taking $\log$ on both sides: $$\implies \,? $$

Note that we have: $$\eta(s) = \frac{1-2^{1-s}}{1-3^{1-s}} \lambda(s) $$ which means that if $s \neq 1$, we get that $$\eta(s) =0$$

Comment: After taking log of both sides:
$$(1−s) \log (2/3)=0$$
$$ \log 2−log 3 = 0$$
$$\log 2 = \log 3$$
which is impossible. However it seems irrationality of the ratio of logs is really not required. They not being equal means both denominators cannot be zero for same (as long as s≠1)

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not seeing any green marks. May be because of I’m using mobile - which I use exclusively? I’ll check it on a laptop when I get a chance. Thanks for the answer! It did help me.